# Rhizosphere vs. Endorhiza?

Tags: botany, microbiology, terminology, etymology

In relation to microbiology and the naming of the various areas of the plant as it relates to microbial inhabitance, I am confused as to the difference between the terms **endorhiza** and **rhizosphere**.

In [this](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=pQyRyIdm7O0C&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=Phyllosphere%20%22stems%22&source=bl&ots=VAvyV0LpP1&sig=GKHLjD6vRhMmZ-Wkt7hi9t17C8M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Mbj6U_CyCI2LuATo3oKIBw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=rhizosphere%20%22roots%22&f=false) case I see rhizosphere referred simply to as the 'roots', but in [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21947430) case I also see endorhiza explained simply as 'roots' also.

However in [*this*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9115091) case, I see a further explanation for endorhiza (which does make sense etymologically): 'internal root tissues'.

Does this mean *endorhiza* is be a sub-term for the area inside the roots, and the larger area of the rhizome in general represented by *rhizosphere*, and that is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Healthy plant growth depends on a microbial community that lives around and inside the roots of plants [(Bais et al. 2001)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11627-001-0122-y). Roots secrete from the roots a number of chemical compounds that influences the microbial community around but outside of the roots. The microbial community can include bacteria, fungi, and single-celled parasites, as well as larger organisms like insect larvae and even roots from other plants. Some chemicals attract certain organisms while other chemicals repel organisms. This community of organisms around the roots is called the rhizosphere [(Walker et al. 2003)](http://www.plantphysiol.org/content/132/1/44.short). The paper by Walker (open access) describes some of the many types of [symbiotic relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiosis) that occur in the rhizosphere.

Endorhiza refers to the internal environment of the root system. The endorhiza contains another microbial community of bacteria and fungi [(Backman and Sikora 2008)](http://worldcocoafoundation.org/wp-content/files_mf/backman2008.pdf). The organisms of this endorhizal community are collectively called endophytes. Like the rhizosphere, the organisms in the endorhiza are important symbiotic species that benefit the health of the plant.

Similar communities have been identified for other regions of the plant, such as the phyllosphere, the organisms that live on the leaves, stems and other plant parts above the ground [(Backman and Sikora 2008)](http://worldcocoafoundation.org/wp-content/files_mf/backman2008.pdf).

> **Citations**
>
> Backman, P.A. and R.A. Sikora. 2008. Endophytes: An emerging tool for biological control. Biological Control 46: 1-3.
>
> Bais, H.P. et al. 2001. Root specific metabolism: The biology and biochemistry of underground organs. In Vitro Cellular & Developmental Biology - Plant 37: 730-741.
>
> Walker, T.S. et al. 2003. Root exudation and rhizosphere biology. Plant Physiology 132: 44-51.

Answer (score 1):

The endorhiza is not the same as Endomycorrhiza. It's the space that AM (endomycorrhiza aka arbuscular mycorrhiza) occupies within the root cell.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Please add some references to complement your response.

Answer (score 0):

The rhizosphere is the *narrow region of soil that is directly influenced by root secretions and associated soil microorganisms* [(wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizosphere#cite_note-2)

And endorrhiza (also termed Endomycorrhiza, AMS or AM) is a special case of the [mycorrhiza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza), a mutualistic relationship between fungi and plant roots, where the fungus cells are stored within the root and not on its surface.